# How to store Restful paths in application C#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I use Windows Form.

There is an class `NetworkManager`, that does requets to server by Restful paths. Paths are just URL.

I have to put these paths to another class for and read them. How to do that?

Just create a new static class with static list of paths? What is the allowable way?

Answer (score 0):

If the values never change, a static class with constant strings declared within would be fine.

```
public static class RestUrls
{
    public const string URL_USER = "";
}
```

Otherwise, consider storing the values in your app.config file.

Comment: Like this: `static constant string URL_USER = ""?`